# SPARQL Query for Ontology

Tags: sparql

I need to reach the restrictions values of individuals within my ontology using SPARQL. For instance following codes are belonged to my ontology. I have to get the min (0.0) and max (0.5) values according to owl:NamedIndividual. 
When I run the following code:

`select ?ind ?min ?max 
 where 
 { 
    ?ind owl:intersectionOf ([owl:someValuesFrom [owl:withRestrictions ([xsd:minInclusive ?min])]] [owl:someValuesFrom [owl:withRestrictions ([xsd:maxInclusive ?max])]] )
 }`

I only get the following result.

[Results Image](https://ibb.co/9vKSRVy)

I need to get min and max values by filtering them according to their individuals and list them as follows.

[Table view](https://ibb.co/r2Ns26D)

How can I do this?

Thanks for your helps.

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.opendatainagriculture.com/ontologies/hazelnutontology#Flat">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.opendatainagriculture.com/ontologies/hazelnutontology#ShapeOfNutApex"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.opendatainagriculture.com/ontologies/hazelnutontology#Topography"/>
    <rdf:type>
        <owl:Class>
            <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.opendatainagriculture.com/ontologies/hazelnutontology#hasPercentegeValue"/>
                    <owl:someValuesFrom>
                        <rdfs:Datatype>
                            <owl:onDatatype rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double"/>
                            <owl:withRestrictions rdf:parseType="Collection">
                                <rdf:Description>
                                    <xsd:minInclusive rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.0</xsd:minInclusive>
                                </rdf:Description>
                            </owl:withRestrictions>
                        </rdfs:Datatype>
                    </owl:someValuesFrom>
                </owl:Restriction>
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.opendatainagriculture.com/ontologies/hazelnutontology#hasPercentegeValue"/>
                    <owl:someValuesFrom>
                        <rdfs:Datatype>
                            <owl:onDatatype rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double"/>
                            <owl:withRestrictions rdf:parseType="Collection">
                                <rdf:Description>
                                    <xsd:maxInclusive rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.5</xsd:maxInclusive>
                                </rdf:Description>
                            </owl:withRestrictions>
                        </rdfs:Datatype>
                    </owl:someValuesFrom>
                </owl:Restriction>
            </owl:intersectionOf>
        </owl:Class>
    </rdf:type>
    <hasTopography rdf:resource="http://www.opendatainagriculture.com/ontologies/hazelnutontology#Flat"/>
    <hasPercentegeValue rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double"></hasPercentegeValue>
    <hasReferenceCultivars rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Impériale de Trébizonde</hasReferenceCultivars>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

Comment: Have you already tried doing a query on your own? If so, can you post a it so we can see what you are doing wrong?

Comment: No. I am trying to do right now. However, I could not do it yet.

Comment: (untested): `select ?ind ?min ?max where {?ind a [owl:intersectionOf ([owl:someValuesFrom/owl:withRestrictions/xsd:minInclusive ?min] [owl:someValuesFrom/owl:withRestrictions/xsd:maxInclusive ?max] )]}`

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, I could not get any query result with this code.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to StackOverflow! As-is, your question is hard to answer, as it's unclear what you have tried sofar, and where you are stuck. Please try to [edit] your question to add more detail. Have a look at [ask] for tips on how to write a good question.

Comment: that one works: `prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
select * where {
?ind a [
 owl:intersectionOf (
    [owl:someValuesFrom [owl:withRestrictions ([xsd:minInclusive ?min])]] 
    [owl:someValuesFrom [owl:withRestrictions ([xsd:maxInclusive ?max])]]
   )
 ]
}` - with SPARQL 1.1 property path you could simplify it a bit

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your helps. I tried and modified your code. I get only one individual's result. I could not reach the others. I am trying to solve this problem. If you have any suggestion about that please share it with me. Thank you.